# How to upgrade React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've understood that I'm using react.js version 15.6.2. I know this because doing this in my code:

```
console.log(React.version);
```

results in this console output:

```
15.6.2
```

I want to upgrade to React@^v16.2.0. I tried doing this:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo n latest
```

But nothing changes. I get the same version output in the console. How do I upgrade node?

EDIT:

Here's the situation, I'm in a project folder with the following hierarchy:

[image]

`node_modules` seems to contain the react installation, since it has a react folder with a `package.json` file containing the version number `15.6.2`.

I've tried both `npm update --save react` and `npm update -g react`. None worked. Same thing happens, and the same version number can be found in `node_modules/react/package.json`. I even tried to run `npm install` again before hosting with `npm start`.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have to tried a simple npm update?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade React or node?

Comment: I am bit confused , what are you trying to upgrade

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade react to version 16.2.0. Sorry, too much coding has scrambled my brain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `npm update --save react` to update to latest version.
For a specific version use `npm update --save react@16.2.0`.

React should not be installed globally but only for your project. If this is not the case use `-g` instead of `--save`

**UPDATE**

Okay my fault. Just use `npm install --save react@16.2.0`. This installs the new version.

Comment: --save is no longer needed. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Kruspe, I tried your solution. Still doesn't work. I put the results in an edit.

Comment: @Pistolpete. In NPM v5 and above, `-S`/`--save` is the default. In v4 and below, you have to specify it. So as long as their Node/NPM installation is up to date, you're correct.

Comment: Okay i updated my answer. This worked for me.

@Pistolpete. if react is already in your package.json --save is not needed otherwise --save adds the dependency to your package.json